# form method=post and action=index.php?page=somepage

Tags: html, forms

I am writing a small script to run on a home server which will handle form data via post, but should submit to a page with get values. I.e. the index.php file receives a $_GET which sets which page is loaded.

If the page index.php?page=form is loaded then a form should appear, this works fine, but the form handling is on the same page.

Having a form like so:

```
<form action="index.php?page=form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    Other form fields here
</form>
```

will post the data to index.php? instead of index.php?page=form.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is working for me. If I press enter, I get to the site index.php?page=form. Maybe your problem is anywhere else.
Here are two options, maybe one of them are useful for you...

Is this possible for you?

If no $_POST is set, the form will displayed, if you submit the form, you can process the datas. So you dont need the get variable anymore.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])): ?>
  <!-- process the inputs -->
<?php else: ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <!-- Other form fields here -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you need the $_GET variable, try

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['page'] == 'form'):
  //process the inputs
else: ?>
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="form">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <!-- Other form fields here -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Having given it a day it has started working. the only thing I can conclude is that it was a caching issue with my browser. I'll accept this answer as it does show the correct method of doing this.